# Unwanted bounce of subviews on scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, subview

I have a scrollview that acts as a banner with 15 image views as subviews (scrolled horizontally). I add the subviews this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < featuredImages.count; i++) {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.frame.size;

    UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    subview.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollViewFeaturedImages addSubview:subview];
}
```

And set the contentSize accordingly:

```
self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.frame.size.width * featuredImages.count, self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.frame.size.height);

self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

However, when the view appears, the first image seems to be a little off.

[image: space between image frame and scroll frame]

When I scroll (horizontally) to the next image, the gap disappears, and when I scroll back to the first image, the frame is corrected already.

I've also disabled BOUNCE but I can drag the image vertically.

[image]

I've also tried this:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

with no success.

What's going on?

Comment: How & where you setting images to those `UIImageViews`?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma 
            [subview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:featured.background_url]]; (setImageWithURL is from a library called SDWebImage; lazy loading)
            subview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

Comment: Can I assume, Image are loading properly from the URL?

Comment: Yes @SuryakantSharma. I have used this library several times. I think the problem lies on the scrollView & its subview though I can't pinpoint what it is

Comment: Did you check the image size before and after loading?

Comment: @KenKuan yes, they're all the same. The Y value of all images are at 0, but the 1st image is still a little off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being puzzled for 2 weeks I finally got this fixed by adding these lines in `viewDidAppear`.

```
self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.scrollViewFeaturedImages.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the UIImageView's property `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's the whole imageView frame that's off when the view appears.